# How to detect or monitor touching edittext in another android app?

Tags: android

Is it possible to monitor touching edit text behavior in another android app? For example, when touching edit text in specific android app, paste some words automatically which have been set up before.
PS. if it is not possible, any way to receive soft keyboard pop up broadcast ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to detect when an `EditText` is touched, even when the `EditText` belongs to another app. However, this can only be done through **Accessibility Services**.

First, you need to create a `serviceconfig.xml` file in your xml folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_permission_desc"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    />
```

Second, you need to create an AccessibilityService, like so:

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
        switch(accessibilityEvent.getEventType()) {
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED:
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED:
                try {
                    Class className = Class.forName(accessibilityEvent.getClassName().toString());

                    if (EditText.class.isAssignableFrom(className)) {
                        // An EditText was Clicked or Focused
                        // Use other methods from the accessibilityEvent to do what 
                        // you need to do
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                 
                break;
        }
    } 

    ...

}
```

Third, you need to add the service to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<service android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/serviceconfig" />
</service>
```

Finally, you need to enable the AccessibilityService through the Accessibility Settings. You can go directly to there through:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS));
```

**Edit:**

You can't get the `EditText` through an `AccessibilityEvent`. Instead, you need to get an `AccessibilityNodeInfo` and perform typical `EditText` features through this `AccessibilityNodeInfo`.

To get the `AccessibilityNodeInfo`, you'll need to call this code:

```
AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = accessibilityEvent.getSource()==null ? null : accessibilityEvent.getSource();
```

Then, you can perform specific actions like `setText()` like so:

```
if (nodeInfo != null) {
    nodeInfo.refresh();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, newString);
    nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, bundle);
}
```

Notice how I'm using `performAction()` onto the `AccessibilityNodeInfo` and using the action `AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT` and passing in a bundle with the key `AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE`.

This is almost the same as calling `setText()` on the EditText View.

If you don't want to `setText()` and want to just directly paste text into the `EditText`, you can use:

```
if (nodeInfo != null) {
    nodeInfo.refresh();
    nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);
}
```

Comment: one more question, it is possible when finish setting text, and then submit automatically?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: sorry, I will be clear more, for example, like forum, when finished a post, then automatically submit rather then click submit button manually.

Comment: If you mean, can you use AccessibilityEvents to detect when an EditText's text has been editted, then yes it's possible. `AccessibiltyEvent` has an event type known as `TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED`. If you listen for this event, then you'll be able to get notified of when the text in an EditText has changed, thus allowing you to do what you need to do.

Comment: my idea, in another app, there are two views, one is edit text and another is submit button, when click edit text, some pre-set characters will be pasted into, and then click submit button to send these characters, for now half work done, pre-set characters can be pasted into edit text field, but still need click submit button manually, so another half work is if or not when edit text being filled, submit button will be clicked automatically.

Comment: another issue is in another app, submit button is being limited to click with specific time, maybe one second, still no idea about how to pass through this time limit.  call system time and set up system time one second advanced? that can pass this time limit?

Comment: If this is a new question unrelated with the question asked in this thread, please start a new Question. You can give me the link to the new question. This is because your new question might require typing an answer in code, which can't be done easily in comments. Comments are also not meant for this. Please create a new question for your new questions.

Comment: ok, Jackey, here is the link of new question. again thanks for your help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642892/automatically-click-submit-button-and-how-to-pass-time-limit-on-submit-button