# Automatically click submit button and how to pass time limit on submit button?

Tags: android, onclick, buttonclick

My idea, in app, there are two `views`, one is `editText` and another is submit `button`, when click `editText`, some pre-set characters will be pasted into the `editText`, and then click submit button to send these characters. For now, half work done is done. Pre-set characters can be pasted into `editText` field, but still need click submit button manually. so another half work is if or not when `editText` being filled, submit button will be clicked automatically. can I set submit button on soft keyboard clicked automatically when `editText` is being filled?

Another issue is in another app, submit button is being limited to click with specific time, maybe one second, still no idea about how to pass through this time limit. call system time and set up system time one second advanced? that can pass this time limit?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: you want to press button only one time or in one second button has to be pressed?

Comment: button is being set time limit, like if you click button once, you can click second time after one second. what I want is edit text is filled on each time, submit button will be click to send at once without time limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `TextWatcher` to monitor the EditText for changes.

You can use a `TextWatcher` like so:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        submitButton.performClick();
    }
});
```

With a `TextWatcher`, you can respond to certain events related to the text entered into the `EditText`. With this example, I'm simulating a click on the Button after text has been changed.

Comment: problem is even edit text is being filled, because of time limit of submit button, still can't send message at once. PS edit text and submit button are all belong to another app

Comment: Simply don't use `performClick()` and just directly use the code within that button's `OnClickListener` instead. This way, you're directly running the code the button will run when pressed without actually pressing the button. There shouldn't be any button delay if you directly run the code instead.

Comment: since submit button is in another app, no idea how to get button id and set up some listeners or methods on it

Comment: any idea? Jackey, if it is impossible, I just give up this

Comment: If you're using AccessibilityEvents to perform the submit button click, the delay is unavoidable.

Comment: ok, thanks for your advice, since I can't get submit button id from outside app, pass such time limit sounds impossible, think I should change idea, if later, I get any progress, I will update this post.